# Revoke access or refresh groups and roles from Azure AD in .NET Core Web App

Tags: azure, authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a file>new .net core web app which is using Azure AD for authentication which works fine out of the box.

I have a requirement to create some auth policies so I have the following code which check the groups in the users claims and sets up an "Admin" policy which I can use on my endpoints.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("groups", "XXXXX"));
        });
```

This works fine too. The problem is once the user is logged in, how can I:-

1. Revoke access if I needed to? (e.g. a user is removed from AD or has his access revoked)
2. Refresh the auth so that if there has been any change in claims, roles, groups etc, it is detected.

I took a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-revoke-access but it doesn't give much. It actually says "It's possible that the app may never send the user back to Azure AD as long as the session token is valid."

How is the best way to handle this?

Comment: I think you can do this by revoking user access tokens and refresh tokens. After you revoke the user's permissions in Azure, then revoke the access token and refresh token and redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: The access token has a lifetime of 1 hour. After 1 hour, it needs to use the refresh token to obtain the access token again. Because the refresh token has a long lifetime, you can revoke it during the refresh token's lifetime.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-revoke-access#azure-active-directory-environment

Comment: How would I go about doing this? As I test, I changed the Groups that a user belongs to but this never seems to get refreshed in the claims, so I dont think it ever works unless the user actually signs out, and then signs back in.

Comment: Actually I lie, it didn eventually catch up like you suggest, but there doesnt seem to be a way to immediately kill off access?

Comment: The document  explains this in detail:  Access tokens can be a security concern if access must be revoked within a time that is shorter than the lifetime of the token, which is usually around an hour. For this reason, Microsoft is actively working to bring [continuous access evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-continuous-access-evaluation) to Microsoft 365 applications, which helps ensure invalidation of access tokens in near real time.

Comment: So is there a work around at this time?

Comment: If the answer is helpful to you, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it to end the thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments and post as an answer:

As I said in the comments, if you need to revoke a user's access rights, then you can do this by revoking the user refresh token. After revoking the user's permissions in Azure, then revoke the  refresh token and redirect the user to the login page.

After the user is authenticated, he will receive the access token and the refresh token.
First, you need to revoke the user's refresh token. The lifetime of the refresh token is 90 days by default, so you need to revoke it during its lifetime. You can use [AAD Power Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0):

```
Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId "a1d91a49-70c6-4d1d-a80a-b74c820a9a33"
```

But as far as I know, the access token cannot be revoked. The default expiration time of the access token is 1 hour. After 1 hour, the user will automatically lose access to AAD.
If you want to terminate user access immediately after the user permissions is revoked, you can try the [continuous access evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-continuous-access-evaluation) provided by Microsoft, which helps ensure invalidation of access tokens in near real time. However, as the documentation says, this may cause security issues, so I think it is not the best method.

So I think the best way is:  just revoke the refresh token, and then wait 1 hour for the access token to expire, the user will automatically lose access to AAD. Then refresh the authentication and redirect the user to the login page.